# Текстура отображается во весь экран

Tags: android, c++, opengles

Хочу отрисовать текстуру 100x100 пикселей.
Tessellator:

```cpp
void Tessellator::Draw(int width, int height) {
    if (!drawing)
        throw std::runtime_error("Isn't drawing");

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float) + texCoords.size() * sizeof(float), nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), vertices.data());
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), texCoords.size() * sizeof(float), texCoords.data());
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    if (true) {
        const char* vertexShaderSource = AssetManager::Get()->GetAssetContent("shaders/texture.vsh");
        const char* fragmentShaderSource = AssetManager::Get()->GetAssetContent("shaders/texture.fsh");

        GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);

        GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

        GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

        glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "position");
        glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 1, "textureCoords");

        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        float left = 0.0f;
        float right = static_cast<float>(width);
        float top = 0.0f;
        float bottom = static_cast<float>(height);
        float near = -1.0f;
        float far = 1.0f;
        glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::ortho(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);

        GLint projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projectionMatrix");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix));

        GLint textureSamplerLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "textureSampler");
        glUniform1i(textureSamplerLoc, 0);
    }

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, reinterpret_cast<void*>(vertices.size() * sizeof(float)));

    glDrawArrays((GLenum) primitiveMode, 0, vertices.size());

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    this->vertices.clear();
    this->colors.clear();
    this->texCoords.clear();
    this->drawing = false;
}
```

Шейдеры
texture.fsh:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

varying vec2 texCoords;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureSampler, texCoords);
}
```

texture.vsh:

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 textureCoords;

varying vec2 texCoords;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

Также я пока не понял, если закомментировать строку gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureSampler, texCoords); то текстуру всё равно будет видно.

Вот так отрисовываю прямоугольник:

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
bindTexture();
Tessellator* t = Tessellator::Get();
        t->Begin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        t->Tex(0, 0)->Vertex(x, y);
        t->Tex(0, 1)->Vertex(x, y + 100);
        t->Tex(1, 1)->Vertex(x + 100, y + 100);
        t->Tex(1, 1)->Vertex(x + 100, y + 100);
        t->Tex(1, 0)->Vertex(x + 100, y);
        t->Tex(0, 0)->Vertex(x, y);
        t->Draw(screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

И вместо того, чтобы увидеть текстуру 100x100 я вижу:
[image: результат]

Comment: Проверьте координаты вершин и текстур, может там кроется свинья